# Inline delegate and With statement

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, delegates, inline, with-statement

Supposed the code below :

```
    BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                         Dim i As Integer = 0
                         Do While i < selectedRows.Count
                           myGridView.SelectRow(myGridView.GetRowHandle(selectedRows(i)))
                           i += 1
                         Loop
                       End Sub))
```

Can anyone explain me the reason why if I write it using the With statement like this :

```
With myGridView
  BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                           Dim i As Integer = 0
                           Do While i < selectedRows.Count
                             .SelectRow(.GetRowHandle(selectedRows(i)))
                             i += 1
                           Loop
                         End Sub))
End With
```

The debugger throws a null reference exception, which I can't explain

Comment: Post the stack trace...

Comment: So if you break when the exception is thrown, can you see which item is null?

Comment: This is all the stack trace I've :  `System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
  Source=IB.Mes.Para.Gui
  StackTrace:
       à IB.Mes.Para.Gui.TTxProgramScreen._Closure$__172-0._Lambda$__0() dans L:\Repos\FactoryFoundation\IB\Mes\Para\IB.Mes.Para.Gui\TTx\TTxProgramScreen.vb:ligne 157
  InnerException: `

Comment: The exception throws at line : 
`.SelectRow(.GetRowHandle(selectedRows(i)))` where selectedRows(i) is 2. So the only value that can be null is "myGridView" and when I explore this item it is not null, I can't understand this.

Comment: Could `GetRowHandle` return null?  Does the code work if you use a local variable instead of the `With`?  (Also, recommend to tag me in a reply so I get a notification.  Use the '@' symbol to do this.)

Comment: @Craig Yes, if I use directly the variable `myGridView` instead of using `With` keyword it works fine ! And `GetRowHandle` doesn't return null value.

Comment: For my money, that indicates a bug in the VB compiler where it isn't capturing the `With` variable correctly.